# Using includeTypes flag on changefeeds

Tags: rethinkdb

From: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/#including-result-types

- Could the `uninitial` be further defined? If `initial` is just an `add` that happened before I started the feed, then how do i get `uninitial`?
- How do I get `state`? With `includeInitial, includeState, includeTypes` set to `true`, I'll get separate state docs, but never a `type: state` interface.

Answer (score 1):

There's a better explanation of what "uninitial" results are in the "Including initial values" section of the document that you linked. To quote:

> If an initial result for a document has been sent and a change is made to that document that would move it to the unsent part of the result set (for instance, a changefeed monitors the top 100 posters, the first 50 have been sent, and poster 48 has become poster 52), an “uninitial” notification will be sent, with an old_val field but no new_val field.

The reason these exist is due to how RethinkDB changefeeds implement the initial results logic. Initial results are processed more or less from left to right in the key space of the table. There is always a slice of the key space for which initial results are being send, and a remaining slice for which the changefeed has started "streaming" current updates in realtime. When you first open a changefeed with `includeInitial: true`, the whole key range will be in the initializing state. Then, as initial results are being sent over the changefeed, the key boundary between the initializing and streaming part moves and more of the keyspace become streaming.

`uninitial` values happen if a document's key moves from a part of the key space that is already streaming, to a part that's still initializing. This can only happen for changefeeds that use secondary indexes, since the primary key of a given document can never change.

Regarding `state`: I seem to be getting the `type: "state"` documents just fine. For example:

```
r.table('t1').changes({includeStates: true, includeInitial: true, includeTypes: true})

{  "state": "ready" , 
   "type": "state" } 

{  "state": "initializing" , 
   "type": "state" }
```

Are you not getting these documents?

Comment: The secondary index part makes sense, thanks!
Yes, I get those state documents, but they are separate (before and after the initial stream). The documentation makes it seem like `state` is going to be a field on a document. See how `state` is right below `uninitial` in the documentation.